# Data from FutureProvider prints two different variables who have same value for an instance only once , why?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a data model Product whose data is stored in firestore. When I read its data using Provider and print the fields of product dim_x and dim_y, I only get values printed which are different. For example,

I have 2 products
P1 with dim_x = 200.0 and dim_y = 100.0
P2 with dim_x = 80.0 and dim_y = 80.0

The print command in my code below prints 80.0 only once, why is that?
({200.0, 100.0}, {80.0})
why not ({200.0, 100.0}, {80.0, 80.0}) is printed?

```
class Product {
  final String pid;
  final double dim_x;
  final double dim_y;
  
  Product(
      {required this.pid,
      required this.dim_x,
      required this.dim_y,})
}

class CreateJob extends StatefulWidget {
  CreateJob({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateJob> createState() => _CreateJobState();
}

class _CreateJobState extends State<CreateJob> {

Future<List<Product>> fetchProductsFromBase() async {
  // .. code for getting data from firestore collection
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        FutureProvider<List<Product>>(create: (_) => fetchProductsFromBase(), initialData: []),
        // ...,
      ],
      child: SafeArea(
//...somewhere down the widget tree
//ScheduledDelivery()
}

class ScheduledDelivery extends StatefulWidget {

  const ScheduledDelivery({super.key});

  @override
  State<ScheduledDelivery> createState() => _ScheduledDeliveryState();
}

class _ScheduledDeliveryState extends State<ScheduledDelivery> {
  late List<Product> productList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    productList = context.read<List<Product>>();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('\n${productList.map((e) => {e.dim_x, e.dim_y})}\n');
// ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [`Set`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.6/dart-core/Set-class.html): `{e.dim_x, e.dim_y}`. `Set` cannot have duplicate value.

You might be looking for [`Record`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.6/dart-core/Record-class.html) instead.

Change `{e.dim_x, e.dim_y}` to `(e.dim_x, e.dim_y)`. Or just use a proper [string interpolation](https://dart.dev/language/built-in-types#strings) to print the values.

Comment: Thanks, Can i also ask it sometimes doesn't print anything when I write productList = context.read<List<Product>>(); in initState as in my code above but it always prints when I write in build function. Can it have any increment cost on firestore reads?